# How do I provide the second match in my regular expression and do full validation?

Tags: regex

I have regular expressions like below. Ancak tam olarak doğru bir şekilde regex yazamadım.

`keys:value,keyx:values,keyt:valus,........` OR `keys:value`

How can I perform an exact match both ways?

regex: `(^\w+:\w+|(,))`

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^\w+:\w+(?:,\w+:\w+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/U6IbOk/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single or multiple occurrence of the key:value parts and matching only word characters, you can match the first occurrence and optionally repeat a comma and then then same pattern using a repeating group.

```
^\w+:\w+(?:,\w+:\w+)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+:\w+` Match the first key:value occurrence
- `(?:,\w+:\w+)*` Optionally repeat using `*` a comma and again a key:value pair
- `$` End of string

See the matches on [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/6DrabH/1).